# Error when calling model method after validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Model called `LearningText` which has two attributes: `webUrl` and `content`

I instantiate the model by passing it a `webUrl` component. From that, I want to generate the `content` by reading the web page with Nokogiri.

I am trying to do that by initializing `content` with the lifecycle method `after_validation`:

```
class LearningText < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_validation: generate_content

private

  def generate_content
    @content = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@webUrl).read)
  end

end
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
models/learning_text.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end after_validation: generate_content ^
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

I should have written

```
after_validation :generate_content
```

rather than

```
after_validation: generate_content
```